# ActiveJob with Resque Adapter (add delay/timeout function)

Tags: ruby, resque, ruby-on-rails-4.2, rails-activejob, resque-scheduler

I'm planning to pass a multiple active job using a loop.
But I need to have a delay/timeout function in each data loop.
My code is like:

```
for s in @saved_jobs
  # ADD delay funtion for each data to pass in ActiveJob Process
  # for ex. every data will pass to background job after every 3minutes
  ActiveCallsJob.perform_later(xxx, xx, x)
end

@saved_jobs = Information from DB
ActiveCallsJob = Class name of ActiveJob
```

Please Help Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It simple. You just need to read the manual: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#enqueue-the-job

```
# Enqueue a job to be performed tomorrow at noon.
MyJob.set(wait_until: Date.tomorrow.noon).perform_later(record)

# Enqueue a job to be performed 1 week from now.
MyJob.set(wait: 1.week).perform_later(record)
```